# Pygame surface changes to object

Tags: python, oop, pygame

So I have a small part of my program here:

```
import pygame

class image(object):


def __init__(self, src):
    self.name = pygame.image.load(src)
    print self.name
def resize_img(img_name, new_length, new_height):

    img_name = pygame.transform.scale(img_name, (new_length, new_height))


robot_img = image("lolz.png")

robot_img.resize_img(robot_img.name, (30, 30))
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: must be pygame.surface, not image
```

What is going on? Any help is much appreciated, and, if needed, I will happily give more information.

Comment: always show full error message - which line makes problem ?

Comment: btw: use "CamelCase" name for class - `class Image` - it helps to recognize class in code.

Comment: @furas it is line: img_name = pygame.transform.scale(img_name, (new_length, new_height))

Comment: do you use `resize_img(..)` only in one place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `self` in `resize_img`

```
def resize_img(self, img_name, new_length, new_height):
```

BTW: you have to use `length` and `width` without `()` in

```
robot_img.resize_img(robot_img.name, 30, 30)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was an awesome answer. Simple, yet informative. Again, thank you!